# AUCteX and LaTeX3 optional arguments

Tags: auctex

LaTeX3 allows for some flexibility in specifying optional arguments to create commands and environments. For example you could specify `\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{d<>m}{...}` and this would be used as `\foo<something optional>{something required}` -- `d<>` specifies an optional argument surrounded by angle brackets. What I would like to be able to do is to color the optional argument in AUCTeX in the same way that occurs with `\section[something optional]{something mandatory}`. Is this possible, and, if so, how accomplished? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add fontification support for your `\foo` like other macros:

1. Customize one of the variables `font-latex-match-function-keywords`, `font-latex-match-reference-keywords` etc. as described in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Fontification-of-macros).  This way, the fontification will be available for `\foo` in all your documents.
   Note that in this case, customize means use the customize interface and don't `setq` it in your init file.  The docstring says:

   > [...] Setting this variable directly does not take effect; restart
   > Emacs.

   Customize has some code to run `(font-latex-match-reference-make)` in this particular case, hence `setq`-ing it doesn't work.
2. In your .tex file, add an entry to the file local variables which can look like this:

   ```latex
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{xparse}
   \NewDocumentCommand\foo{d<>m}{...}

   \begin{document}

   \foo<optional>{mandatory}

   \end{document}

   %%% Local Variables:
   %%% mode: latex
   %%% TeX-master: t
   %%% eval: (font-latex-add-keywords '(("foo" "<{")) 'reference)
   %%% End:
   ```

   It looks like this for me:
   [image]
3. Finally, if you have your definition in a .sty file and load it via `\usepackage`, you have to write an AUCTeX style file and put some lisp code there.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: I should have pointed out in my question that I tried in my .emacs file: `(setq font-latex-match-reference-keywords
  '(
    ("foo" "*[<")
  )
  )` but that this did not seem to work.

Comment: @sgmoye - See my updated answer.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the information!